# Can nuclear intercontinental missiles be launched into space to destroy asteroids menacing Earth?

Tags: space, nuclear-weapons, asteroids

Wikipedia states that intercontinental ballistic missiles can fly a minimum of 5500 kilometers, can we shoot these missiles into space to reach beyond the thermosphere and explode on contact with an asteroid? Could we really shatter an asteroid as in Hollywood movies? I'm not talking about rockets built for space flight, I'm talking about those hidden nuclear rockets hidden under farms in the US for example. This would be a desperate attempt, not much time to prepare and adapt the rockets due to space monitoring blackout because of war reasons. If not possible to launch them into space what changes would need to be made? Fuel? Rocket structure?

[image]

[Image source](https://futurism.com/where-does-earth-end-and-space-begin)

Comment: Related https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/46452/could-nuclear-weapons-divert-or-destroy-an-asteroid - which answers half of your question.

Comment: The key challenges to such an attempt are the nature of the rocket fuel, whether that fuel incorporates its own oxygen for combustion in the higher atmosphere layers, targeting a high speed approaching asteroid as it dips into our gravity well, last minute course corrections, and available megatonnage compared to the mass and density of the target.  Throw in the need for radio receiver of the self-destruct mechanism to function at orbital distances, so that any off-target missiles don't later become new nuclear asteroids.  This isn't a simple yes/no scenario and lots can go wrong.

Comment: @HenryTaylor: ICBMs are real rockets, they are not air-breathing. And they *do* fly into space, they just have suborbital trajectories (that's why they are called "ballistic"). See Zeiss Ikon's answer.

Comment: ICBMs without redesign - no chance. Redesigned ICBMs (with warhead turned into a bomb-carrying spaceship) - probably.

Comment: @Alexander A couple current orbital launchers are ICBMs with updated guidance and lightened payload.  Don't recall the current name, but one is a reformed MX, four stage all solid propellant; it'll put several hundred kilos into LEO (instead of delivering several tonnes point to point up to about 8000 km in original configuration).  Titan (that launched Gemini), Atlas (Mercury orbital launches) and even Redstone (suborbital Mercury) were missiles originally (Redstone was short range, a few hundred km).

Comment: @Zeiss Ikon of course this is all possible - but our mission is significantly more difficult than just putting several hundred kilos into LEO. After reaching LEO, warhead should be able to intercept an asteroid moving at much higher speed.

Comment: @Alexander Hence my answer below.

Comment: @Zeiss Ikon got it now. I was confused about your exact viewpoint.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As built and installed in silos, those missiles aren't capable of reaching low Earth orbit, never mind going beyond it.

This is because, as with everything in rocketry, they're built to deliver the maximum payload (the actual warhead bus with its MIRVs) to the maximum design range, typically (for American and Soviet/Russian missiles) an over-the-pole flight of around 6000-8000 km -- and with the standard warhead bus, that's the most they can do.

Of course, the same rocket (booster and upper stages) could launch a significantly lighter payload much further/higher, perhaps even to escape velocity (to be able to hit the asteroid further out -- always better than last-minute, because more of the fragments will miss Earth), but reconfiguration, even as simple as removing all but one warhead from the MIRV bus, would take days or weeks.  Beyond that, the guidance systems of those missiles are designed to accurately target a location on the surface of Earth, not give meters- and millisecond-level precision to a 4D location.  The likelihood of a hit (for a missile originally built only to get within a few hundred meters of a stationary target) would be abysmal.

You should also be aware of the story behind the [recent headlines](https://www.sciencealert.com/our-last-line-of-defence-against-an-asteroid-hit-actually-works-study-shows) concerning "last minute" fragmentation of an asteroid: they're talking two to six *months* before impact, which gives the small change in velocity of the fragments time to disperse them so most either miss the Earth entirely or just graze the atmosphere.  Fragmenting an incoming rock pile a few hours before impact, never mind within the thermosphere (minutes out) would make things *worse* by converting a single immense impact into a hemispheric "burning sky" that would literally ignite everything on dry land underneath it -- so instead of destroying a continent, it'll destroy half the planetary surface.

As suggested in comments, a rocket with orbital delta-V (about 7.9 km/s after gravity, drag, and steering losses) can only go about 6500 km straight up.  From there, another 1.3 km/s will reach a trans-Lunar orbit, still almost two kilometers per second short of escape velocity needed to hit an incoming rock two to six months out and actually make most of its mass miss the Earth.

Comment: "Those missiles aren't capable of reaching low Earth orbit, never mind going beyond it" - but you don't need to go into orbit to kill an asteroid, you can just go straight up. Some 90% of the energy stored in a rocket is spent in achieving orbital *speed*, only about 10% is spent in achieving altitude. If you just need a rocket to go up but not *stay* up, you can go a *lot* higher. I agree it's not feasible, but the comparison to LEO doesn't seem like a useful starting point.

Comment: @Nuclear Hoagie reaching LEO is a necessary step if we want this interception system work. Otherwise hitting incoming asteroid head-on is like hitting incoming bullet with your own bullet.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie Yes and no.  Anyone who's played Kerbal Space Program with Realism Overhaul knows you can go thousands of km high with a rocket that can't make orbit -- but the *closest* you'd ever want to nuke an asteroid is beyond the Moon's orbit, and to go that far, it's about the same delta-V whether you launch direct or boost to a parking orbit (and the launch window is much wider for parking orbit).

Comment: Added link to the headlines about "last minute" defense.

Comment: @Alexander LEO just makes targeting easier - it's hard to go through the atmosphere into a very specific trajectory, and much easier to do from a stable orbit. But there's no reason why you couldn't have the collision at the apex of the rocket's trajectory (or even on the rocket's way back down) to reduce impact velocity. In fact, it's the LEO rocket that is has a bigger problem with impact velocity, as it needs to bleed off all its orbital speed to bring its earth-relative velocity to zero!

Comment: @ZeissIkon Totally agree that for useful asteroid-killing altitudes, we're talking about similar delta-V. Might be worth adding to the answer - a rocket that can't achieve LEO can temporarily go far higher than LEO, but still not high enough to be useful for this purpose. Without running the numbers, it's not immediately obvious that an inability to achieve LEO implies an inability to reach the necessary altitude.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie We'll assume escape velocity can go anywhere (it can, if you're patient); that's about 11 km/s.  Orbit is 7.9 (recalling from KSP/RO).  It's an old, old saying that LEO is halfway to anywhere in the Solar System, measured in delta-V.  But 7.9 km/s equates to at least 62 MJ/kg which is roughly 6500 km strictly by kinetic = potential calculation.  WAY too low.  You can make LEO into an orbit with 6500 km apogee for only about 1 km/s.

Comment: @Nuclear Hoagie "there's no reason why you couldn't have the collision at the apex of the rocket's trajectory" - no reason. It's just as I said - as unlikely as hitting one bullet with another.

Comment: @Alexander we have guidance systems that can do just that -- shoot down incoming warheads by direct impact.  Combine that with a fast-acting proximity fuse, and you're done -- but you aren't going to throw that together in a few weeks from detecting an incoming object until last possible launch time to avoid catastrophe...

Comment: @Zeiss Ikon "we have guidance systems" - not on the ICBMs or their warheards, those are on surface-to-air missiles, and we don't have engines hoping to match asteroids' speed. Our only hope here is that the warhead would get exactly into the path of incoming asteroid.

Comment: I disagree.  An unmodified ICBM doesn't have a seeker to get the required accuracy, nor a suitable fusing system, but neither are impossible to add.  I can see value in equipping some ICBMs that way--while engaging a large rock at point blank range is counterproductive shooting at something like the Tunguska object is another matter.  An ICBM as it sits in it's silo has the range and firepower to smash such an object--worth it if it's going to hit a city.

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what I said, @Alexander -- look up "kinetic kill" antimissile defense.  Ground launched at very high G from near the predicted impact point.  They still aren't anything like as fast as the incoming ICBM bus, but they can get close enough for extended arms to score direct contact (at a relative velocity that will break up the incoming vehicle).  That guidance system, however, couldn't be grafted to an ICBM launcher in a reasonable time, and without extensive testing there would be no way to verify the accuracy.

Comment: You'd be better off ditching the warheads entirely, and just flying the rocket up with no payload other than its own fuel, to attach itself to the asteroid, and then keep rocketing to gently nudge it off of the collision course.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Except with an ICBM it'll take nearly all the fuel just to intercept, more than the initial load to match velocity, and then you want fuel left to push the asteroid.  Rocket deflection is a decades-out approach.  Impact deflection *might* work with days, likely will with months.

Answer (score 3):

It depends. All of the early rockets, at least in the United States, I'm not sure about the USSR, started life as missiles, and then were converted into tools for spaceflight. Given enough time (years) you can add upper stages to these missiles to loft payload to low earth orbit. Many modifications would have to be made. I'm not super familiar with the design specifications for ICBMs, but to my knowledge they use different fuel from orbital rockets and they are not built to withstand the load of extra stages that you would need for any kind of asteroid deflection.

However, as the above answer said, I would caution against this kind of deterrent against an asteroid within the atmosphere, or even closer than the distance of the Moon. Heck, even far out in deep space. The safest way to protect against asteroid is to catch it years in advance, send a small spacecraft to it, and then have the spacecraft fire an engine, perhaps an ion thruster, for a long period of time. This would eventually nudge it out of the way so that it never endangers Earth.

Detonating a nuclear warhead against an asteroid is usually just a really, really bad idea. It turns a bullet into buckshot. Movies depicting humanity being saved at the last moment by some team of people detonating a nuke on an asteroid just wouldn't be how it happens.

That being said, a nuclear impact against an asteroid isn't *always* bad - but nuclear routes for mitigating asteroids are far more precise than simply hitting it with an ICBM. You would need to hit the asteroid in a specific direction so that the buckshot goes away from earth, or detonate a bunch that are in specific locations on the asteroid - it would basically need more precision than just hitting it, and would be better if done in advance.

NASA and other space agencies are tracking an immense number of asteroids, and while they have the potential to miss city killer asteroids, civilization destroying ones are usually easier to spot. You'd have to have a really good reason for why we have lost our defense against asteroids, such as it being a post apocalypse. Even right now, NASA said:

"In May 2021, NASA astronomers reported that 5 to 10 years of preparation may be needed to avoid a virtual impactor based on a simulated exercise conducted by the 2021 Planetary Defense Conference." (from the wikipedia article linked below)

If you need a sense of urgency for your story, I would recommend placing the asteroid further back, and just stressing that when it gets past a certain point, there's certain doom. Perhaps there is some kind of impactor, almost like driving a spike into it, that could deflect an asteroid but not shatter it. There is much research on this, particularly look up NASA's upcoming DART mission which will deflect an asteroid. I'll caveat this all with that our research into asteroid defense is still in its infancy, and that there are many proposed ways to mitigate these threats.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asteroid_impact_avoidance

The wikipedia article will lead you to a number of resources that will likely help, especially in terms of prevention methods and what characteristics you want for your asteroid.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation.

Comment: You're welcome, there's a lot of leeway that you could go with this, as a decade of preparation doesn't make it easier to construct a narrative, so don't fret too much if you stretch the facts a bit.

Comment: @current: When you edit, you should actually *correct* earlier mis-statements, not just add a note at the bottom.  Assume that future readers will be reading the whole answer from the start, and write for their benefit.  Specifically, you probably want to say something about burying the charge inside the asteroid before detonation being necessary to make anything useful happen, instead of just saying it's always useless.  (If I have that right.)

Comment: @PeterCordes noted, and modified accordingly.

Comment: Much better, nice edit.  (One sentence is missing some words in the phrase *in specific direction that the buckshot*, probably "such that the buckshot" and "in *a* specific..."; I make the same kind of mistakes myself when editing and changing my mind on phrasing things)

Comment: @PeterCordes is that better?

Comment: Yup, just a minor copy-edit was all that was still needed.

Answer (score 1):

### It depends on trajectory, the impactor, and the Rambo factor.

Every now and then a meteor [really does bounce off the atmosphere](https://phys.org/pdf520590204.pdf).  The rock doesn't have to be small, and some have claimed the immense [Tunguska explosion](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-8287993/Tunguska-event-caused-asteroid-bounced-space.html) was such an object.

Given *very, very good modelling* of a type not really available at present, I can imagine being so sure that an object will just barely dig in to the atmosphere and destroy a city, that you want to give it a "nudge".  I'm not sure what effect using a nuke to heat some layer of the atmosphere, or to vaporize some of the material on the underside of the impactor, would actually have.  That's what supercomputers are for.  But if you're truly desperate to find some use for those old nukes you have lying around (and who isn't?) then you can postulate just the right circumstance to make it happen.  Like Rambo avoiding enemy bullets, this is purely a matter of probability.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR: Big asteroids that pose a serious threat require nuclear explosives so powerful that they're more dangerous to the Earth than the asteroid might be.** Small asteroids might be doable, but the consequences of failure are low enough that they might not be plot-interesting.

Don't set off Earth-shattering kabooms a mere 5000km up. Intercept your asteroids a long, *long* way away.

---

> I'm not talking about rockets built for space flight, I'm talking about those hidden nuclear rockets hidden under farms in the US for example.

Once upon a time, the rockets used to launch things into space *were* the same rockets use to deliver nuclear warheads to the other side of the world. The Soviet [Proton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_(rocket_family)) rocket family started life as something capable of throwing a 100MT warhead 13000km. The [Titan II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGM-25C_Titan_II) started out as something intended to carry a 9MT warhead, but was also notable for lifting the [Gemini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Gemini) spacecraft into orbit that pioneered techniques later used for the Apollo program.

> can we shoot these missiles into space to reach beyond the thermosphere and explode on contact with an asteroid?

Intercepting something with relative speeds of many kilometres a second is a moderately challenging thing to do... it isn't something that people are necessarily very good at even now. The kind of trajectory changes and guidance systems needs are totally unlike anything you'd expect to find on an ICBM. What you'd need is basically a whole new upper stage spacecraft to do the final interception.

Missiles *could* be modified for this... the Titan II is one obvious example, but other and smaller missiles have been adapted into launch platforms like the [Minotaur](https://arstechnica.com/science/2021/06/cold-war-era-missile-launches-three-modern-day-spy-satellites/) that's build on top of a Minuteman II missile. The act of building an intercept-capable spacecraft is technically possible now, but gets increasingly difficult as your tech level goes back towards early cold war times.

> Could we really shatter an asteroid as in Hollywood movies?

Oh, absolutely. A very rough handwavey approximation for the oomph required to shatter something might be simply the volume of the object times its tensile strength, giving you a nice value in joules.

Lets imagine a stony asteroid big enough to cause serious problems... lets make it a sphere, 1000m in diameter, made of carbonaceous chrondrites. Weighs about a billion tonnes. Delivers an equivalent yield of ~16 gigatonnes, that sort of thing. Anything smaller is much less of a serious threat... bad for the country it hits, but for everyone else life goes on, so it should be at least this big.

Chrondrites aren't super tough... they've only got a tensile strength of ~10MPa. Given the volume of this asteroid, if you delivered about 1.25MT of boom to it, you could in fact shatter it. Easy peasy.

Now you have the problem of a billion tonnes of *gravel* falling to Earth, with pretty much the same kinetic energy... you've still got a catastrophe, its just a slightly different flavour of catastrophe.

What you need, then, is to make sure that all the gravel is accelerated well away from Earth, so there's no danger of it dropping straight down or falling into an unstable orbit and dropping down later on. Lets get a ballpark figure for the difficulty of this by working out how much kinetic energy the gravel would need to have to be leaving at escape velocity. Escape velocity at ~5000km up is about 8.4km/s, giving a kinetic energy of ~4x10<sup>19</sup> joules, or a bit shy of 10 gigatonnes. And remember, this is a ballpark figure that ignores the kinetic energy the asteroid already has. Oh yeah, and because you won't be using nuclear shaped charges, at least half the blast of your warhead is wasted, so you'll need something closer to a **20 gigatonne warhead**.

Teller (of [Teller-Ulam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermonuclear_weapon#Basic_principle) thermonuclear bomb design fame) imagined nuclear explosives of such size... they had codenames like [GNOMON and SUNDIAL](http://blog.nuclearsecrecy.com/2012/09/12/in-search-of-a-bigger-boom/), for "things that cast shadows". They might be *possible* to build, but it seems tricky to fit them onto a normal ICBM, and when the super-heavy missiles I listed above existed no-one was seriously imagining they could make a multi-gigatonne bomb let alone a *moveable* one.

If you did manage to make one, and get it up there, and blow it up close enough to the asteroid, you're gonna have *Problems* on the planet below. It is hard to work out what sort of atmospheric damage will be done, but radiant flux at the surface directly below the blast could easily be hot enough to set things on fire. The damage and death will be enormous. I can't quite tell if it is better or worse than letting the asteroid hit. The fact that there's some ambiguity here should give you pause for thought... the asteroid won't produce long-lived radioactive fallout, for starters.

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems with this scenario. The first concerns the weapon. When talking about missiles it is helpful to break it down into the following sections

[image]

This application would call for a new upper stage that combines the payload and  guidance sections: an autonomous vehicle that will be able to track the incoming asteroid and deliver its weapon to it, providing some course-correction thrust (also called terminal guidance) and time the detonation circuit for the nuclear weapon to coincide with impact. Without that ignition circuit signal, it will just smash harmlessly into the rock without detonating. I would say it would look something like the Raytheon [Exo-Atmospheric Kill Vehicle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exoatmospheric_Kill_Vehicle)

[image]

This hypothetical payload vehicle would need thrusters, sensors and a sophisticated real time control system so it could perform the terminal stage autonomously. It will take time to develop and test this system -- and if you try to short-circuit / rush the R&D process it will fail miserably when needed. If you want it in action in time for this moment it should probably have been out of the labs and into testing 10 years ago, with the first operational units online and being fitted onto existing missile boosters just now.

The second problem concerns the Asteroid. And that is simply that nukes are not magic asteroid erasers. If you're talking about a big, world-threatening asteroid made primarily out of chondrite and silicate rock... well let's just take the asteroid Bennu as an example.

diameter: 490 meters

mass: 73 million metric tons (0.000073 * 10^15 kg)

It takes about 10 gigajoules to vaporize 1 metric ton of silicate rock. Therefore it would take 730,000 terajoules to vaporize Bennu. The B41 / Mk-41 nuclear bomb (most powerful US weapon ever) has a yield of 25 megatons, the equivalent of 100,000 terajoules.

So Bennu would lose about 10% of its mass in that explosion, which is significant. But.. not enough. Even Tsar Bomba, the largest weapon Russia ever tested (50MT) would not be enough. And it is worth pointing out that those are not *small* weapons, they were huge. Delivering them into space would require titanic rockets and a specialized heavy duty kill vehicle.

So if we aren't going to erase the asteroid, what are we going to do?

Comment: "if you try to short-circuit / rush the R&D process it will fail miserably when needed" .. this is the exact opposite of a space asteroid movie. :)  Just shine a lot of lasers on the asteroid, scotch tape a cell phone to the warhead under the fairing and program it to recognize a large blob of red light.  (You already have this on hand, because yesterday your daughter was showing you her program to recognize soft drink cans for purposes of product placement in the movie you're starring in.)

Comment: @MikeSerfas lawl right? Sort of like "drill 10 miles and then set off the nuke. Drive 10 miles into Texas, are you in the middle of Texas?

Comment: What kind of lunatic would drill ten miles underground to do a nuclear weapons test in Texas?  It's better for the environment and treaty obligations to do those underground nuclear tests in space. :)